# Script is getting pass with out clicking the element

Tags: java, selenium

The Below code I was writing , where the element will get store in list , and  click randomly using the java random method and after clicking it should print the success message

ISSUE : the Code is getting pass and printing the success message without clicking any web-element

```
 List<WebElement> ev_Collection = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='collection-card']");
    
                Random random = new Random();
    
                int index = random.nextInt(ev_Collection.size());

                System.out.println("the bound is "+ index) ;
   
                ev_Collection.get(index).click();

                   System.out.println("Success ");
```

Do I need to change the above code please let me know

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like right now there's no conditional for testing if anything was clicked. Rather the code is running sequentially and the last line to be run is a print statement.

Try using a ClickHandler and putting the print statement inside that.